# Search for words in SQL Server index

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, full-text-search

I need something in between a full text search and an index search:
I want to search for text in one column of my table (probably there will be an index on the column, too, if that matters).

Problem is, I want to search for words in the column, but I don't want to match parts.

For example, my column might contain business names:
  *Mighty Muck Miller and Partners Inc.

  Boy & Butter Breakfast company*

Now if I search for "*Miller*" I want to find the first line. But if I search for "*iller*" I don't want to find it, because there is no word starting with "iller". Searching for "*Break*" should find "*Boy & Butter Breakfast company*", though, since one word is starting with "*Break*".

So if I try and use

```
WHERE BusinessName LIKE %Break%
```

it will find too many hits.

Is there any way to Search for Words separated by whitespace **or other delimiters**?

(LINQ would be best, plain SQL would do, too)

**Important:** Spaces are by far not the only delimiters! Slashes, colons, dots, all non-alphanumerical characters should be considered for this to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2000 or above.

```
SELECT *
  FROM dbo.TblBusinessNames
 WHERE BusinessName like '%[^A-z^0-9]Break%' -- In the middle of a sentence
    OR BusinessName like 'Break%'            -- At the beginning of a sentence
```

Keyword Reference for **LIKE**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933232(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: Whoah, cool, this is it - I'll have to add some foreign characters (äöüÄÖÜß), but it's way better than creating funky regex procs!

Answer (score 6):

Your word delimiters are going to be many: space, tab, beginning of line, parentheses, periods, commas, exclamation/question marks etc. So, a pretty simple solution is to use a regex in your WHERE clause. (And it's going to be a lot more efficient than just ORing every possible delimiter you can think of.)

Since you mentioned LINQ, here's an article that describes how to do [efficient regex querying with SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx).

Complicated WHERE clauses like this always raise a red flag with me as far as performance is concerned, so I definitely suggest benchmarking whatever you end up with, you may decide to build a search index for the column after all.

**EDIT:** Saw you edited your question. When [writing your regex](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx), it's easy to just have it use any non-alphanum character as a delimiter, i.e. [^0-9a-zA-Z], or \W for any non-word character, \b for any word boundary and \B for any non-word boundary. Or, instead of matching delimiters, just match any word, i.e. \w+. Here's [another example](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/regular-expressions-in-t-sql) of someone doing regex searches with SQL Server (more complicated than what you'd need).

Answer (score 4):

```
where BusinessName like 'Break%' -- to find if it is beginning with the word
or BusinessName like '% Break%' -- to find if it contains the word anywhere but the beginning
```

Comment: So I would have to add an "or like" for every possible delimiter, like slash, colon, dot...?
*Boy and Butter-Breakfast company*

Comment: No, if you have more delimiters (you specified this later), then this is not a good solution. Maybe you can try regular expressions if you are using SQL 2005 or SQL 2008, or thinking about full text search.

Comment: Actually it was in the text from the start (or other delimiters), but since everyone missed these three words I chose to highlight them and additionally add some more explanation about this - sorry, had been hidden very well beforehand.

Comment: You may want to create yourself a 'search column', i.e. same as Business Name, but where you replace all your punctuation etc with a standard delimiter, like '|'. You can use a view for that. Then just search for '|Break%'.

Comment: Sorry, I also missed that part. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE BusinessName LIKE '% Break%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned LINQ - you could do something like...

```
string myPattern = "% Break%";

var query =
      from b in Business
      where SqlMethods.Like(b.BusinessName, myPattern) 
      select b;
```

Note that this uses the `System.Linq.Data.SqlClient` namespace which translates directly to the `LIKE` operator with no additional processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @vSearch nvarchar(100)

set @vSearch = 'About'

select * from btTab where ' ' + vText + ' ' LIKE '%[^A-z^0-9]' + @vSearch + '[^A-z^0-9]%'
```